# Xamarin.Forms ListView not displaying items even when setting IsVisible to true

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

**Description:**
I'm working on a Xamarin.Forms application, and I'm currently facing an issue with my ListView not displaying items even after setting IsVisible to true. I've followed the Xamarin documentation and other examples, but I'm still unable to identify the problem.

**XAML (MainPage.xaml):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="BeautyFly.MainPage"
             BackgroundColor="#404040">

    <StackLayout>
        <!-- First ScrollView with Button -->
        <StackLayout>
            <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Text="File" BackgroundColor="Transparent" TextColor="White" Clicked="Button_Clicked" TextTransform="None"/>
                    <Button Text="Settings" BackgroundColor="Transparent" TextColor="White" Clicked="Button_Clicked" TextTransform="None"/>
                    <Button Text="Filters" BackgroundColor="Transparent" TextColor="White" Clicked="Button_Clicked" TextTransform="None"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
            <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10,0">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ImageButton Source="a" HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="60" Aspect="AspectFit" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
            <!-- Add more elements as needed -->
        </StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="menuListView" IsVisible="false">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10,5">
                            <Image Source="icon" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" />
                            <Label Text="Hi hello world" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**Code-Behind (MainPage.xaml.cs):**

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace BeautyFly
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            menuListView.IsVisible = true;
        }

        private void menuListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //menuListView.IsVisible = false;
            switch (e.SelectedItem)
            {
                case "open":
                    break;
            }
            //menuListView.SelectedItem = null;
        }

        private void ImageButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayAlert("helL", "o", "h");
        }
    }
}
```

Issue:

I have a ListView named myListView.
I'm initializing an ObservableCollection and setting it as the ItemsSource.
Despite setting IsVisible to true, the items are not displaying.
Things I've Checked:

Verified that the data in the ObservableCollection is populated correctly.
Checked for any layout issues or conflicting properties.
Question:
Can anyone help me identify why the items in my ListView are not displaying even when I set IsVisible to true? Is there something I might be missing or any common pitfalls I should look out for?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Edit:

my new xaml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="BeautyFly.MainPage"
             BackgroundColor="#404040">

    <StackLayout>
        <!-- First ScrollView with Button -->
        <StackLayout>
            <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Text="File" BackgroundColor="Transparent" TextColor="White" Clicked="Button_Clicked" TextTransform="None"/>
                    <Button Text="Settings" BackgroundColor="Transparent" TextColor="White" Clicked="Button_Clicked" TextTransform="None"/>
                    <Button Text="Filters" BackgroundColor="Transparent" TextColor="White" Clicked="Button_Clicked" TextTransform="None"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
            <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10,0">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ImageButton Source="a" HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="60" Aspect="AspectFit" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
            <!-- Add more elements as needed -->
        </StackLayout>
        <ListView ItemSelected="menuListView_ItemSelected" IsVisible="false">
            <ListView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>mono</x:String>
                    <x:String>monodroid</x:String>
                    <x:String>monotouch</x:String>
                    <x:String>monorail</x:String>
                    <x:String>monodevelop</x:String>
                    <x:String>monotone</x:String>
                    <x:String>monopoly</x:String>
                    <x:String>monomodal</x:String>
                    <x:String>mononucleosis</x:String>
                </x:Array>
            </ListView.ItemsSource>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

and c#:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace BeautyFly
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listView.ItemsSource = new string[]
{
  "mono",
  "monodroid",
  "monotouch",
  "monorail",
  "monodevelop",
  "monotone",
  "monopoly",
  "monomodal",
  "mononucleosis"
};
        }
        private ListView listView = new ListView();
        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //menuListView.IsVisible = true;
        }

        private void menuListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //menuListView.IsVisible = false;
            switch (e.SelectedItem)
            {
                case "open":
                    break;
            }
            //menuListView.SelectedItem = null;
        }

        private void ImageButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayAlert("helL", "o", "h");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are not setting an `ItemsSource` so there is no data for the `ListView` to display

Comment: How can i set items for it? (I tried the normal way before)

Comment: either use binding or just explicitly assign `ItemsSource`.  I have no idea what the "normal way" is

Comment: Well can you write me an answer assigning the `ItemSource`?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding

Comment: It's not working also i want with image on it.

Comment: please [edit] your question to show what you've tried

Comment: Question edited.

Comment: if you have already created the `ListView` in XAML, you do NOT need to also create it in the code behind.   And the `ListView` in your XAML does not have a `DataTemplate`, so it does note have any UI defined to display.

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about but it shows those items but nothing else happens.

Comment: What "else" do you expect to happen?   The code in `menuListView_ItemSelected` does not actually do anything, if that is what you are expecting.

Comment: I remove those slashes before run my code so yes it actually do a thing.

Answer (score 0):

After taking a deep into the issue, it looks like there's a potential when set `IsVisible`  using `ListView`, however, you can use `CollectionView` as an alternative option.

Also, you need to use the `BindingContext` to show the items you clicked in `ListView`:

```
  var grid = (Grid)sender;
  var item = grid.BindingContext;
  DisplayAlert("Hello", item.ToString(), "Cancel");
```

Here's the demo below for your reference:

**Code-behind:**

```
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {

        //public ICommand GetItemCommand => new Command<string>(async () => await GetItemCommandAsync());
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = this;  
         
    }


       private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
             menuListView.IsVisible = true;
       }
   
        private void ImageButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayAlert("helL", "o", "h");
        }


        private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
        {

            var grid = (Grid)sender;
            var item = grid.BindingContext;
            DisplayAlert("Hello", item.ToString(), "Cancel");
        }
    }
```

**XAML:**

```
      <StackLayout>
        <!-- First ScrollView with Button -->
        <StackLayout>
            <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Text="File" BackgroundColor="Transparent" TextColor="White" Clicked="Button_Clicked" TextTransform="None"/>
                    <Button Text="Settings" BackgroundColor="Transparent" TextColor="White" Clicked="Button_Clicked" TextTransform="None"/>
                    <Button Text="Filters" BackgroundColor="Transparent" TextColor="White" Clicked="Button_Clicked" TextTransform="None"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
            <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10,0">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ImageButton Source="a" HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="60" Aspect="AspectFit" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
            <!-- Add more elements as needed -->
        </StackLayout>

     
            <CollectionView x:Name="menuListView"  IsVisible="false" >
                <CollectionView.ItemsSource>
                    <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                        <x:String>mono</x:String>
                        <x:String>monodroid</x:String>
                        <x:String>monotouch</x:String>
                        <x:String>monorail</x:String>
                        <x:String>monodevelop</x:String>
                        <x:String>monotone</x:String>
                        <x:String>monopoly</x:String>
                        <x:String>monomodal</x:String>
                        <x:String>mononucleosis</x:String>
                    </x:Array>
                                     
                </CollectionView.ItemsSource>

                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Label FontSize="Medium" Text="{Binding .}"/>
                   
                            <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                            </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Grid>
                       
                       
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                           
            </CollectionView>
 
    </StackLayout>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: That's what i did after that but i want the list to show as something like `DisplayAlert` (or `MessageBox` in normal c# code) i don't want it to appear as a part of elements in screen.

Comment: @FDr Thanks for the update, I have updated my answer, you can refer to it.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT Collection view does not have ItemTapped evetn handler ? Why do you use TapGestureRecognizer ?

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT this is `DisplayAlert` it's not selectable. (i want to select between multiple items)

Comment: @FDr Thanks for the response, you can click on the items of the listview and show it respectively on the alert, what do you mean select between multiple items?

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listview?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: @FDr please point out which part you want to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listview?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT A listview like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin-media/xamarin.forms/_images/listview.triplescreenshot.png?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: The code is here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listview?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT It's not working.

Comment: @tomatobar I've tested it on my side, it's working, see [my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZc7i.png), why is not working? Can you provide more details?